# Is there a better way to implement "string contains substring" in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I am looking for better options in Javascript to check if a string contains a substring. Substring can either be a text from an input field or database.

Sample:

```
var substring = "DVI to VGA" //some code to get text from input field or database
var string = "12 DVI To VGA adapter"

if(string.toLowerCase().indexOf(substring.toLowerCase()) != -1){
    //any action after match
    console.log("FOUND A MATCH")
}
```

Comment: a regex can do the trick too.

Comment: Define "better"

Comment: What you got looks good to me but es6+ has `String.includes`.

Comment: But `String.includes` doesn't provide case insensitive comparison/search. So it's either the current approach or a RegExp

Comment: @Thomas, you're right, so you'd have to pull the same `.toLowerCase` trick, but at least you can avoid the index comparison.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't think of any, but you can encapsulate what you have in a function that is more concise and reusable:

```
function stringContainsSubstring(string, substring) {
    return string.toLowerCase().indexOf(substring.toLowerCase()) != -1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

var contains = (string.toLowerCase()).includes(substring.toLowerCase());

Comment: "This method has been added to the ECMAScript 2015 specification and may not be available in all JavaScript implementations yet"

Answer (score 0):

not exactly a solution, but you can use it like:

```
if(~string.toLowerCase().indexOf(substring.toLowerCase()){...
```

looks a bit cleaner